# Event Sourcing with DynamoDB and Exactly Once Delivery, should I sort by AggregateId?

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb, cqrs, event-sourcing, dynamodb-queries

Hi friends of big data!

I am planning on implementing an event sourcing model with DynamoDB and Elixir for an internal simple messaging system. The purpose of this particular table in DynamoDB will be to log a meaningful history of events of messages (the payload will be stored elsewhere).

Here is my initial approach...

```
Domain/TeamId: Primary partition key, splits events by domain (different teams .etc.). This will avoid creating too many partitions.
EventId: Snowflake (RangeKey)
Timestamp: SomeTimestamp
ProfileId: String
MessageId: String
Type: String
AggregateId: String (LSI)
```

The EventId will represent the version, and the AggregateId will initially represent the aggregate of messages per profile using `profileId_<a_profile_id>_messageId_<a_message_id>`. I'll fire events to the table like whether a message is read or deleted. I'll then use an aggregateId as the range key with = semantics to aggregate all of the events. This is to support a kind of running history of messages per profile.

The only side effect I can think of is there will be no guarantees on the order of events when querying for a particular aggregate. But if an aggregate is a reduce over all events, does this *really* matter?

Using this I plan to support exactly once delivery semantics by checking to see if the eventId has been updated for a particular team, and if it has check the aggregate again to make sure we're not adding two `MessageRead` events (we only want to track whether a message has been read once and when it was read). If somehow superfluous events end up, I'll handle this on the aggregate model.

Can I clarify whether this seems like an acceptable approach? It's difficult to come up with an exact title because this is a relatively nuanced and complex issue. Elixir doesn't exactly lend itself to perfect CQRS implementations, but I want to make sure I capture enough data to implement a canonical event sourcing model partitioned for our use case.

- Please be advised I don't have control over the database technology or language!
- Due to this constraint the idea of the aggregate key is just to make it easier to query less data, however I have to sacrifice sort order if the aggregateId isn't the partition key  because there's just nothing to range on, makes me dubious!

Answer (score 0):

This response is 1.5 years late. Hopefully you are enjoying your successful system, but I'll post this answer for future searchers.

Firstly, regarding naming of TeamId or Domain. I would go as generic as possible for this name. A successful event-sourcing system will be used for cases which you've never previously considered.  This is why most event-sourcing installations name this field "StreamId". I'll refer to it as this.

Monotonically increasing IDs or Versions in a Stream (or Domain, in your case) are important for any consumers of your events. If you have multiple writers to your event-stream, this becomes difficult.  Snowflake can generate monotonically increasing IDs, but only on a single process. So if you want monotonicity, then you need some sort of consensus.

> Using this I plan to support exactly once delivery semantics by
>   checking to see if the eventId has been updated for a particular team,
>   and if it has check the aggregate again to make sure we're not adding
>   two MessageRead events (we only want to track whether a message has
>   been read once and when it was read).

Excellent. Presumably you're using Conditional Writes in dynamo to achieve this effect. If you are, then you are already achieving all of the consistency that you need to set those EventId values to anything that you want.  I would argue that you may as well set the ID's to increment by exactly 1 for every new record for a particular Stream.

Having increments of exactly 1 for a stream are important for 2 reasons:

1. Order probably does matter. Not for all cases, but for most
   applications, you do need to process events in order.  If you're
   counting, or performing other commutative operations, then maybe
   not.  However, most business applications can't be expressed in
   order-independent operationts. Again, if you're going through the
   hassle of building this system, you might as well take some simple
   steps to make it useful for a variety of cases.
2. Missed messages indicator.  If all of your services/actors are only reading from the dynamo table, this is less important.  However, if you have a distributed system with some sort of message delivery, then each actor can confidently build their own aggregations and projections if they can be sure that they are processing all messages (and only once)

Comment: Thank you for your response. The engineering was a huge success in this project and we all enjoyed the fruits of our labour whenever asked to implement a feature. Unfortunately though, the product itself failed!